# Get the css of a column header of a GridView

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I'm using a custom sorting in a GridView which works by clicking on the header text to sort by that column. Now I want to add a little arrow next to text of the header to indicate the direction of the sorting. I'm doing that with the css style and it works. The problem is that by doing so, the css style that was previously set (in the aspx file) is gone.

To counter this one would think that it's only a matter of getting the current css style string and append the new style. Easier said than done.

I've tried:

```
gvDocs.HeaderStyle.CssClass;   // returns an empty string
gvDocs.HeaderRow.CssClass;   // returns an empty string
gvDocs.HeaderRow.Cells[i].CssClass;   // returns an empty string
gvDocs.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Attributes["class"];   // returns null
LinkButton lb = gvDocs.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
lb.CssClass;   // returns an empty string
lb.Attributes["class"];   // returns null
```

I tried putting the code almost everywhere but it's always the same result.

Next is a snippet of the aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDocs" runat="server" CssClass="table" ...
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="doc_number" HeaderText="#" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="doc_number" ShowHeader="True">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="vert-align" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="vert-align" />
        </asp:BoundField>
...
```

**Not every header has the same css style** so I really need to know what's the current style and append the one to show the arrows.

I'm updating the css style in the `gcDocs_Sorting` event like this:

```
 gvDocs.HeaderRow.Cells[GetColumnIndex(Session[GV_ORDERS_SORT_FIELD].ToString(), gvDocs)].CssClass += " sortDesc";
// or "sortAsc", depends on the result of a previous `if`.
```

So how can I get the current css of column header?

Answer (score 0):

You can just let the GridView add css classes for sorting automatically

You can do this in code:

```
gvDocs.SortedAscendingHeaderStyle.CssClass = "sorted-asc";
gvDocs.SortedAscendingCellStyle.CssClass = "sorted-asc";
gvDocs.SortedDescendingHeaderStyle.CssClass = "sorted-desc";
gvDocs.SortedDescendingCellStyle.CssClass = "sorted-desc";
```

Or directly on your GridView's markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDocs" runat="server" 
    SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sorted-asc"
    SortedAscendingCellStyle-CssClass="sorted-asc"
    SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sorted-desc"
    SortedDescendingCellStyle-CssClass="sorted-desc">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: That won't work. That applies the style to all headers, not individually.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, it will only add the class to the column that has been sorted...